# Connection refused for Flink with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-flink

I have the following docker-compose file which is a copy of the docker-compose from the docker apache flink site. The only difference is that I am using the Mac m1 version.

```
version: "2.2"
services:
  jobmanager:
    image: arm64v8/flink:alpine
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    command: standalone-job --job-classname com.job.ClassName [--job-id <job id>] [--fromSavepoint /path/to/savepoint [--allowNonRestoredState]] [job arguments]
    volumes:
      - ~/sg_flink/artifacts:/opt/flink/usrlib
    networks:
      - flink-network
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
        parallelism.default: 2

  taskmanager:
    image: arm64v8/flink:alpine
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
    command: taskmanager
    scale: 1
    volumes:
      - ~/sg_flink/artifacts:/opt/flink/usrlib
    networks:
      - flink-network
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
        taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 2
        parallelism.default: 2
networks:
  flink-network:
```

The error is a connection is refused

```
taskmanager_1  | 2021-11-03 17:43:02,724 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor            - Could not resolve ResourceManager address akka.tcp://flink@9cf35ea13c8b:6123/user/resourcemanager, retrying in 10000 ms: Could not connect to rpc endpoint under address akka.tcp://flink@9cf35ea13c8b:6123/user/resourcemanager..
taskmanager_1  | 2021-11-03 17:43:12,753 WARN  akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport                    - Remote connection to [null] failed with java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: 9cf35ea13c8b/172.20.0.3:6123
taskmanager_1  | 2021-11-03 17:43:12,756 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@9cf35ea13c8b:6123] has failed, address is now gated for [50] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@9cf35ea13c8b:6123]] Caused by: [Connection refused: 9cf35ea13c8b/172.20.0.3:6123]
taskmanager_1  | 2021-11-03 17:43:12,758 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor            - Could not resolve ResourceManager address akka.tcp://flink@9cf35ea13c8b:6123/user/resourcemanager, retrying in 10000 ms: Could not connect to rpc endpoint under address akka.tcp://flink@9cf35ea13c8b:6123/user/resourcemanager..
```

docker ps output looks like this

````
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                              NAMES
4416f88f60c2   arm64v8/flink:alpine   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   44 seconds ago   Up 44 seconds   6123/tcp, 8081/tcp                 sg_flink_taskmanager_1
c211940acf41   arm64v8/flink:alpine   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   45 seconds ago   Up 44 seconds   6123/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp   sg_flink_jobmanager_1
```
````

Answer (score 0):

I have met this trouble in same condittion,and I fixed it use docker-compse links.

```
taskmanager:
  links:
    - jobmanager
```

Answer (score 0):

To sorry, I can't to see who owns an address 172.20.0.3
What helped me in the same situation:

1. check your taskmanager can connect to 'jobmaster:6123'(I used flink:1.17-scala_2.12, so it possible you don't need install a netcat):

   ```
   docker exec -it sg_flink_taskmanager_1 /bin/bash
   apt-get update
   apt-get install -y netcat
   nc -vz jobmaster 6123
   ```

if you get 'Connection refused' please check whether your containers are in the same network(or your hostnames are actually taskmanager and jobmanager).

if you get 'Connection to jobmanager (here is jobmanager IP address) 6123 port [tcp/*] succeeded!' go to the next step.

2. you can check either your default flink parameters in flink-conf.yaml within the taskmanager contaner or logs of the taskmanager contaner:

- The properties file /opt/flink/conf/flink-conf.yaml had  in my case:

  ```
   jobmanager.rpc.address: taskmanager (Look! this is by default and wrong for this utilize! It must be jobmanager)
   taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 1(Look! it is by default, it must be 2)
   parallelism.default: 1(Look! it is by default, it must be 2)
  ```
- The taskmanager contaner logs had the same as above wrong values:

  ```
   INFO  [] - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.address, taskmanager
   INFO  [] - Loading configuration property: parallelism.default, 1
   INFO  [] - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots, 1
  ```

3. So I saw that '|' didn't work for some reason and to make sure I tryed this line:

   ```
    - "FLINK_PROPERTIES=jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager\ntaskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 2\nparallelism.default: 2\njobmanager.rpc.port: 6123"
   ```

in the docker-compose file and it handed over my env.

Comment: Opted not to continue with Flink unfortunately. So can't verify.