# Flink - Run cluster and submit Job in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-flink, flink-streaming

### Problem

I'm following a project tutorial on learning to use Apache Flink, and I decided to deviate a bit by making the code fully containerized with Docker.

My code structure is the following:

[image]

My Docker compose run 3 containers: Flink job manager, Flink task manager and one to submit a job to Flink.

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  jobmanager:
    image: flink:1.18.1-scala_2.12-java17
    container_name: jobmanager
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
    networks:
    - flink-network
    command: jobmanager
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/flink/project

  taskmanager:
    image: flink:1.18.1-scala_2.12-java17
    container_name: taskmanager
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
        taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 2
        parallelism.default: 2
    networks:
      - flink-network
    command: taskmanager
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/flink/project

  startjob:
    image: flink:1.18.1-scala_2.12-java17
    container_name: startjob
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
        parallelism.default: 2
    networks:
      - flink-network
    command: /opt/flink/bin/flink run -c FlinkStreaming.DataStreamJob target/flink-streaming-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/flink/project
    working_dir: /opt/flink/project


networks:
  flink-network:
    external: true
```

The JAR application launched in `startjob` is already built and works fine.

DataStreamJob

```java
package FlinkStreaming;

import Deserializer.JSONValueDeserializationSchema;
import Dto.Transaction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.WatermarkStrategy;
import org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.KafkaSource;
import org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.initializer.OffsetsInitializer;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;

public class DataStreamJob {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Sets up the execution environment, which is the main entry point
        // to building Flink applications.
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        String topic = "eco2mix-national-tr";

        KafkaSource<Transaction> source = KafkaSource.<Transaction>builder()
                .setBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
                .setTopics(topic)
                .setGroupId("flink-group")
                .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
                .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new JSONValueDeserializationSchema()).build();

        DataStream<Transaction> transactionDataStream = env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Kafka source");

        transactionDataStream.print();

        // Execute program, beginning computation.
        env.execute("Flink Java API Skeleton");
    }
}
```

Transaction

```java
package Dto;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Transaction {
    private String date_heure;
    private Integer consommation;
    private Integer prevision_j1;
    private Integer prevision_j;
    private Integer fioul;
    private Integer charbon;
    private Integer gaz;
    private Integer nucleaire;
    private Integer eolien;
    private Integer eolien_terrestre;
    private Integer eolien_offshore;
    private Integer solaire;
    private Integer hydraulique;
    private Integer pompage;
    private Integer bioenergies;
    private Integer ech_physiques;
    private Integer taux_co2;
    private Integer ech_comm_angleterre;
    private Integer ech_comm_espagne;
    private Integer ech_comm_italie;
    private Integer ech_comm_suisse;
    private Integer ech_comm_allemagne_belgique;
    private Integer fioul_tac;
    private Integer fioul_cogen;
    private Integer fioul_autres;
    private Integer gaz_tac;
    private Integer gaz_cogen;
    private Integer gaz_ccg;
    private Integer gaz_autres;
    private Integer hydraulique_fil_eau_eclusee;
    private Integer hydraulique_lacs;
    private Integer hydraulique_step_turbinage;
    private Integer bioenergies_dechets;
    private Integer bioenergies_biomasse;
    private Integer bioenergies_biogaz;
    private Integer stockage_batterie;
    private Integer destockage_batterie;
}
```

JSONValueDeserializationSchema

```java
package Deserializer;

import Dto.Transaction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.DeserializationSchema;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation;
import org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;

public class JSONValueDeserializationSchema implements DeserializationSchema<Transaction> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public void open(InitializationContext context) throws Exception {
        DeserializationSchema.super.open(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Transaction deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
        return objectMapper.readValue(bytes, Transaction.class);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEndOfStream(Transaction transaction) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public TypeInformation<Transaction> getProducedType() {
        return TypeInformation.of(Transaction.class);
    }
}
```

However, submitting the job like so gives me the following error: `org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /0.0.0.0:8081`

Here's the full log (the main errors):

```bash
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: Failed to execute job 'Flink Java API Skeleton'.

Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Failed to execute job 'Flink Java API Skeleton'.
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils$RetryException: Could not complete the operation. Number of retries has been exhausted.
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /0.0.0.0:8081
Caused by: org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /0.0.0.0:8081
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

I also want to precise that, before the containerization of the job submission, it worked perfectly fine the manual way (command line to submit the job).

### What I expect

I'm expecting the job to be successfully submitted to Apache Flink, and be able to see it on the localhost dashboard.

### What I tried

First, I made sure my cluster was running. I'm able to correctly access the Flink dashboard at `0.0.0.0:8081`, so it should be good.

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69829539/connection-refused-for-flink-with-docker-compose), I tried to add a `link` component within the `taskmanager` containers, but no success.

#### Update

While reading the Flink documentation, I came across the `--target` and `-m` arguments from the `run` command which are, if I understood correctly, used to specify the cluster location.

Using this information, I tried to modify my docker compose the following:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  jobmanager:
    image: flink:1.18.1-scala_2.12-java17
    container_name: jobmanager
    expose:
      - "6123"
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
    networks:
    - flink-network
    command: jobmanager

  taskmanager:
    image: flink:1.18.1-scala_2.12-java17
    container_name: taskmanager
    expose:
      - "6121"
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
        taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 2
        parallelism.default: 2
    networks:
      - flink-network
    command: taskmanager

  startjob:
    image: flink:1.18.1-scala_2.12-java17
    container_name: startjob
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
    networks:
      - flink-network
    command: /opt/flink/bin/flink run -m jobmanager:6123 -c FlinkStreaming.DataStreamJob target/flink-streaming-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/flink/project
    working_dir: /opt/flink/project


networks:
  flink-network:
    external: true
```

But now, it's raising a new error:

```bash
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: Failed to execute job 'Flink Java API Skeleton'.
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils$RetryException: Could not complete the operation. Number of retries has been exhausted.
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.ConnectionClosedException: Channel became inactive.
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.ConnectionClosedException: Channel became inactive.
```

While using the `--target`:

```yaml
command: /opt/flink/bin/flink run --target jobmanager -c FlinkStreaming.DataStreamJob target/flink-streaming-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The error changes for:

```bash
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: No ExecutorFactory found to execute the application.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ExecutorFactory found to execute the application.
```

Not really sure if I'm on the right way

Comment: Can you update your question to include the snippet of code that shows the connection to the job manager please?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt What do you mean by the code snippet for the job manager? Is it my JAR application? (sorry, I'm new to Flink)

Comment: LOL me too ;) But yes, your Java code. It looks like it's trying to connect within the container, instead of to the job manager container. It will look fine from your host machine because you've exposed port 8081, but remember that your code is running without its own container.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I added all my Java source files. Of course, you don't have access to the Kafka stream, but we should still be able to submit the job to Flink. We should just get on timeout error within the dashboard at some point...
Hope that could help

Comment: `.setBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")` => should you not set ports in docker to "8081":"9092" (or the other way around, I am too new to docker...)

Comment: @Luuk Seems to be a good path. I'm investigating

Comment: @Luuk Tried multiple configurations but don't seem to resolve the problem. However, I discovered the `--target` and `-m` argument from the Flink run command, and it should be more about this.